# Peculiar behavior when reading an MKL_INT from a file

Tags: c, gcc, intel-mkl

When trying to read a single integer value from a file into a variable of type `MKL_INT` I was confronted with peculiar behaviour in my program that I can't quite understand.

***This short code illustrates the problem:***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mkl_types.h>

void readFile(MKL_INT *a, char *fn)
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(fn, "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%d", a);

    fclose(fp);

    if(*a == 1)
        printf("a == 1 in readFile()\n");
}

int main()
{
    MKL_INT a;
    char *fn = "data.dat";

    readFile(&a, fn);

    if(a == 1)
        printf("a == 1 in main()\n");

    /* Once the last line is commented out, (a == 1) in main() as well as
       (*a == 1) in readFile() yield "false" */
    MKL_INT b = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

*The compilation command I use is*

```
gcc -DMKL_ILP64 -m64 test.c -o test -I$MKLROOT -L$MKLROOT
```

*The file `data.dat` simply contains*

```
1
```

*I observe the following*

- As long as the last line with the declaration of `b` is there, a seems to be read from the file properly and yields `true` in both comparisons
- Once I comment out the last line, both comparisons yield `false`

The only clue I have so far is that the compiler flags seem to play a role here: removing `-DMKL_ILP64 -m64` from the flags results in the program running as expected unconditionally of the last line...

**My system details are**

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- Compiler: GCC 4.8
- MKL: 11 v3

I have never experienced behaviour like this before and would be quite excited to understand what exactly is happening here.

Comment: Your program works for me with and without `MKL_INT b = 1;` commented out. What compiler are using and version of MKL?

Comment: Thanks for trying IKavanagh, I added more details to the question

Comment: It works perfectly under `icc` but exactly as in your question under `gcc`. I too would be interested in understanding why this happens, I've actually recently noticed similar behaviour myself when using MKL with `gcc` but not had time to debug as `icc` is readily available to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to the wrong format specifier in your readFile function.

In my header at hand MKL_INT == MKL_INT64 == long long int or __int64.
For reading these ints you need to use the correct format specifier otherwise it is undefined behaviour.

long long int is read with "%ll" and __int64 is read with "%I64d". So you need to check what MKL_INT is exactly on your system.